# Sorting using Apache flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

Can the data we ingest be sorted using Flume?

I have designed a simple multi-channel flume agent which would ingest data into two directories in HDFS. But what I am not aware of is if flume supports sorting between these two channels.

So far what I am assuming to get out of this is, my source is gonna be a spool directory., whenever I enter lines (each line consisting a unique key word), the line has to go to a certain channel.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting: no. But I don't think that's what you mean.

Consider using an interceptor and a [fan-out flow](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#fan-out-flow) to achieve what you want.